# Google EarthEngine: No command named earthengine

Tags: python, pip, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I am trying to install Google EarthEngine for Python. I am following the instructions listed out in this tutorial: https://www.earthdatascience.org/tutorials/intro-google-earth-engine-python-api/.

When I run Python shell, and execute `import ee`, it imports Google EarthEngine without error. However, in order to use Google EarthEngine, I need to input my authentication credentials (`ee.Initialize()` spits out an error saying I need to do so through the command `earthengine authenticate`). However, when I run `earthengine authenticate`, I get the following error:

> 'earthengine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This seems strange, considering that `earthengine` is installed automatically when the Python API is installed (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line).

What I ran: `py -c "import ee; ee.Initialize()"`

Complete Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 230, in get_persistent_credentials
    tokens = json.load(open(oauth.get_credentials_path()))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\windows/.config/earthengine/credentials'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ee\__init__.py", line 114, in Initialize
    credentials = data.get_persistent_credentials()
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py", line 240, in get_persistent_credentials
    raise ee_exception.EEException(
ee.ee_exception.EEException: Please authorize access to your Earth Engine account by running

earthengine authenticate

in your command line, and then retry.
```

Comment: show the complete error message. what is the name of your script?

Comment: @eyllanesc Updated question.

Comment: Apparently the `earthengine` command is *not* automatically installed. Why did you think that?

Comment: @mkrieger1 https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line states that it is automatically installed

Comment: What was the result of step 5 of the tutorial you’re following; `pip install earthengine-api`?